# Installment system with invoice dividing in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, invoice, accounting

I'm fighting with something for a couple of days and I really need help from You because it's too difficult for me.
There are many debtor customers of the company I work in. Sometimes they cannot pay off all debt so they would like to pay off their arrears in installment/loan system. I'm working on it using VB.NET. I have to prepare the shedule which will divide every installment for individual invoices. I could easily split invoices to installments with payment deadlines for each one, but after that, in the second step, I have to divide each installment on invoices. There is an example of this accounting made manually in Excel for 2 exemplary invoices below. I know that loops used in the code should have 2 "if" conditions: Condition1: Installment amonunt < Invoice amount and Condition2: Installment amonunt >= Invoice amount, but app user (employee of the debt collection department) can generate mixed shedule (various amounts of each installment) where both of condition can be met.
Additionally the simplification is that the program will not charge interest at all (higher level[! decision).
I'll be very thankful for any help or any clue to solve this problem.
Maybe some of You have had such a problem before 
Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: Please ask a specific programming question. What code is not behaving as expected. Show the code you have tried for the specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

For accounting application, we have a matching table to bridge between the invoice and receipt(Instalment). When an instalment is scheduled, you match to the invoice accordingly base on FIFO. So you need to update the data to the matching table and at the same time you need to have a Amount Match and Amountunmatched field on you invoice to keep track of the partial payment.

so when the first schedule is done

Instalment : Inst 1 
Invoice    : Inv A 
Amtmatched : 50 
MatchDate  : 2021-05-15 
Debtor : ABC

At the same time you need update the Invoice A amountmatched to 50 and amountunmatched to 106.53 (outstanding)

2nd Instalement

Instalment : Inst 2 
Invoice    : Inv A 
Amtmatched : 50
MatchDate  : 2021-06-15 
Debtor : ABC

3rd Instalement

Instalment : Inst 3 
Invoice    : Inv A 
Amtmatched : 50 
MatchDate  : 2021-07-15 
Debtor : ABC

4th Instalement, you need to update 2 records

Instalment : Inst 4 
Invoice    : Inv A 
Amtmatched : 6.53
MatchDate  : 2021-08-15 
Debtor : ABC

Instalment : Inst 4 
Invoice    : Inv B
Amtmatched : 43.47 
MatchDate  : 2021-08-15 
Debtor : ABC

You can see this patter is very similar to your table.

On the programming part, you need a date input of startdate, and number of instalment to work the amount for each instalment and the last instalment. You can use the oustanding divide by the outstanding and round it off and get the round off figure allocate to the last month.

Save the instalment schedule to a table first. After that loop the instalment schedule and generate the matching table and update the invoice outstanding for each loop. If you think this method can do the trick and you need further help. You just buzz me.

Comment: The logical code You wrote is correct, but the question is how to make automate loop to calculate it? I tried to loop on invoices table first and then on installment table using various conditions like:

'for i=0 to sheduleGrid.Rows.Count -1
--some conditions
       for j=0 to invoiecesGrid.Rows.Count -1
           --some conditions
      Next 
--insert rows to 3rd table
Next

but without expected result. I would be very pleased if You write out those loops. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you are using sql database. I provide u the code roughly tomorrow.. got some project to finish off..

Answer (score 0):

This is the database diagram and some data sample[image]

This is the program UI
[image]

I will put in the number of instalment I want to schedule and Instalment prefix to generate the transaction no for the instalment.

Here goes the code

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class frmInstalment

    Private Sub btnGenerateInstalment_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGenerateInstalment.Click

        Dim TotalOustanding = Modws.GetDecimalFromQuery("Select Sum(amtunmatched) from Invoice")
        Dim InstNo As Integer = Val(txtInstalmentNo.Text)
        Dim Balance = TotalOustanding

        Dim i As Integer = 1

        Do Until i = InstNo + 1

            Dim InstalAmount = Math.Ceiling(TotalOustanding / InstNo)
            Balance = Balance - InstalAmount

            Dim Amount As Decimal

            If Balance > 0 Then
                Amount = InstalAmount
            Else
                Amount = InstalAmount + Balance
            End If


            Dim InstalNo As String = txtInsalPre.Text & i.ToString("00")

            Modws.UpdateItem("Insert into Instalment(TransNo,Instalment,Amount) Values('" & InstalNo & "'," & i & ", " & Amount & ")")

            i = i + 1
        Loop

        Modws.DisplayDataGrid(dgvInstalment, "Select TransNo,Instalment,Amount from Instalment Order by TransNo")

        For x = 0 To dgvInstalment.Rows.Count - 1
            AddMatching(dgvInstalment("TransNo", x).Value, Val(dgvInstalment("Amount", x).Value))
        Next

        Modws.DisplayDataGrid(dgvResult, "Select * from Matching Order by Instalment")

    End Sub


    Private Sub AddMatching(InstalmentNo As String, InstAmt As Decimal)

        Dim StrConn As String = My.Settings.ImportLinkCS
        Dim CN = New SqlConnection(StrConn)


        CN.Open()

        Dim StrSql As String = "Select * from Invoice Where AMTUNMATCHED <> 0 order by transdate, TransNo"

        Dim cmdReader As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(StrSql, CN)
        cmdReader.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        Dim SdrReader As SqlDataReader = cmdReader.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        'SdrReader = cmdReader.ExecuteReader

        Try
            With SdrReader
                If .HasRows Then
                    While .Read

                        If .Item("Amtunmatched") > InstAmt Then
                            Modws.UpdateItem("Update Invoice set amtmatched = amtmatched + " & InstAmt & ",amtunmatched =  amtunmatched - " & InstAmt & " Where TransNo = '" & .Item("TransNo") & "'")
                            Modws.UpdateItem("Insert into Matching(Invoice,Instalment,Amtmached,InvOutstanding) " + _
                                             "Values('" & .Item("TransNo") & "','" & InstalmentNo & "', " & InstAmt & "," & (.Item("Amtunmatched") - InstAmt) & " )")

                            Exit Sub
                        Else

                            Modws.UpdateItem("Update Invoice set amtmatched = Total,amtunmatched = 0 Where TransNo = '" & .Item("TransNo") & "'")
                            Modws.UpdateItem("Insert into Matching(Invoice,Instalment,Amtmached,InvOutstanding) " + _
                                             "Values('" & .Item("TransNo") & "','" & InstalmentNo & "'," & .Item("AMTUNMATCHED") & ",0 )")

                            InstAmt = InstAmt - .Item("Amtunmatched")



                        End If

                    End While
                End If
            End With
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
        End Try



    End Sub

    Private Sub btnReset_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click

        Modws.DeleteItem("Delete from Instalment")
        Modws.DeleteItem("Delete from Matching")
        Modws.UpdateItem("Update Invoice set amtmatched = 0, amtunmatched = Total")
    End Sub
End Class
```

You also need to add a module class in your program

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports ImportLink.GridPrintPreviewLib

Module Modws

  Public Function GetDecimalFromQuery(ByVal SQLQuery As String) As Decimal
        Dim StrConn As String = My.Settings.ImportLinkCS
        Dim CN = New SqlConnection(StrConn)

        GetDecimalFromQuery = 0

        CN.Open()

        Dim StrSql As String = SQLQuery

        Dim cmdReader As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(StrSql, CN)
        cmdReader.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        Dim SdrReader As SqlDataReader = cmdReader.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        'SdrReader = cmdReader.ExecuteReader
        'GetDoubleFromQuery = 0
        Try
            With SdrReader
                If .HasRows Then
                    While .Read
                        If .GetValue(0) Is DBNull.Value Then
                            'GetDoubleFromQuery = 20
                            'MsgBox("Null Value")
                        Else
                            If IsDBNull(.GetValue(0).ToString) Then
                                'GetDoubleFromQuery = 50
                                'MsgBox("Null Value")
                            Else
                                GetDecimalFromQuery = .GetValue(0).ToString
                            End If
                        End If
                    End While
                Else
                    'MsgBox("No Row")
                End If
            End With
            CN.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
        End Try
    End Function

 Public Sub UpdateItem(ByVal SqlQuery As String)

        Dim StrConn As String = My.Settings.ImportLinkCS
        Dim CN = New SqlConnection(StrConn)
        Try
            CN.Open()

            Dim StrSql As String = SqlQuery

            Dim cmdupdate As New SqlCommand(StrSql, CN)
            cmdupdate.CommandText = StrSql
            cmdupdate.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message & SqlQuery, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error-UpdateItem")
        End Try

        CN.Close()
        CN = Nothing
    End Sub

Public Sub DisplayDataGrid(ByVal dgv As DataGridView, ByVal SQLSTR As String)
        dgv.DataSource = Nothing
        Try
            Dim dbBindSource As New BindingSource
            Dim strCon As String = My.Settings.ImportLinkCS
            Dim strSQL As String = SQLSTR

            Dim dataAdapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, strCon)
            Dim commandBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter)

            'Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource.
            Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable()
            table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
            dataAdapter.Fill(table)
            dbBindSource.DataSource = table


            'Resize the DataGridView columns to fit the newly loaded content.
            dgv.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader)
            dgv.DataSource = dbBindSource

            dgv.Columns(2).Width = 200
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "error")
        End Try
    End Sub

End Module
```

And This is the result I'm getting
[image]

I have tried and it is working fine. In addition, you just need to add customer parameter so that it will process base on the customer.

Comment: This solution is awsome, but I cannot implement it in my app, because rules of making installment shedules are different a little than this. Is there any way to loop only using dgv rows/columns and fill the 3rd dgv instead of using SQL table? The problem is that program user can create the shedule using autosheduler or create it manually installment by installment with deadline and installment amount defining. My program should generate 3rd table independent of various amounts of installments (for example 100.00, 130.00 and 150.00). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes of course, it would be the same concept. Create a dgv with the column similar to the invoice and loop it over using the same concept. While loop the record inject the result to dgv matching.